# Where am i supposed to call a method in view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to implement code to push the scroll up if hidden under keyboard.
First part in the code it says "Call this method somewhere in your view controller" Where is that supposed to be in the view did load? should i write 
     [self.registerForKeyboardNotifications};
?? please help.

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
        name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one place you could call this is in viewWillAppear.
you want to use the line

```
[self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
```

make sure that on view disappear you remove yourself from the notification center aswell.

Comment: And to remove i simple write: registerForKeyboardNotifications=nil;

right?

Comment: you probably want to write a resignFromKeyboardNotifications method, and within that call [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:*put the notification name here* object:nil] for each notification you are observing